# Japanese Spouse Applying for UK Indefinite Leave to Remain - Koseki Tohon or Marriage Certificate?

Tags: united-kingdom, residency, marriage, japanese-citizens

My wife is currently in the process of drawing up her application for ILR in the UK using form SET(M). She's been in the UK for 4 years now.

Among the documents that are required with the application are a birth certificate and a marriage certificate. Does anyone have any idea whether a copy and translation of my wife's *koseki tohon* (family register) is enough to satisfy these requirements, or do you actually need a marriage certificate and birth certificate? In Japan those documents don't generally exist and are subsumed in the *koseki tohon*, which contains all that information.

Would appreciate any help you can give. She came originally on a marriage visa and extended it through the FLR(M) form but neither of us can remember if last time we just submitted the *koseki tohon* or we included other documents.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this US embassy page](http://japan.usembassy.gov/e/acs/tacs-marriagedoc.html), there -is- a separate record, that is kept by the "Legal Affairs Bureau" for 27 years.  I'm not sure what exactly that is, but it might be worth a shot if the *koseki tohon* is insufficient.